# Heap corruption using calloc

Tags: c

I am working with a nice little problem here, and my code almost works.

Now here is my problem.

Im trying to allocate a tree of fields with floats like this:

```
float ** PermLaster;
float ** VarLaster;
```

Then later on I use calloc

```
PermLaster= (float **) calloc(AntPermLast, sizeof(float*));
VarLaster= (float **) calloc(AntVarLast, sizeof(float*));
```

Then calloc again in a nested for:

```
for (StegLastAnt= 0; StegLastAnt <  sizeLastM;StegLastAnt++)
{
    AktLast = inLastP[StegLastAnt];
    if (StegLastAnt > 0)
        {
            OldAktLast=inLastP[StegLastAnt-1];
        }

    if (((int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+7])== 0)||(int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+6])== 0)) && (AktLast != OldAktLast))
        {
            PermLaster[NumPerm] = (float *) calloc(AntAktuell*6, sizeof(float));
            AntLastVekt[NumPerm]=AntAktuell;
            NumPerm++;
            AntAktuell=0;
        }


    if ((int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+7])== 1) && (AktLast != OldAktLast) && (int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+6]) != 0))
    {
            VarLaster[NumVar] = (float *) calloc(AntAktuell*6, sizeof(float));
            AntLastVekt[NumPerm+NumVar]=AntAktuell;
            NumVar++;
            AntAktuell=0;
    }
    AntAktuell++;
}
```

No errors so far.

Then all elements are assigned:

```
  for (StegLastAnt= 0; StegLastAnt < sizeLastM;StegLastAnt++)
        {
        AktLast = inLastP[StegLastAnt];
        if (StegLastAnt > 0)
            {
                OldAktLast=inLastP[StegLastAnt-1];
            }

        if (((int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+7])== 0)||(int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+6])== 0)) && (AktLast != OldAktLast))
            {
                PLastP = PermLaster[NumPerm];
                RadPos=StegLastAnt-AntAktuell;

                for (StegLastAnt2 = 0;StegLastAnt2<AntAktuell;StegLastAnt2++)
                {
                    PLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+0]=float(inLastP[1*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+1]);PLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+1]=float(inLastP[2*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+2]);PLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+2]=float(inLastP[3*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+3]);PLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+3]=float(inLastP[4*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+4]);PLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+4]=float(inLastP[5*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+5]);PLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+5]=float(inLastP[6*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+6]);
                    RadPos++;
                }
                NumPerm++;
                AntAktuell=0;
                PLastP=nullptr;
            }
        if ((int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+7])== 1) && (AktLast != OldAktLast) && (int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+6]) != 0))
        {
                VLastP = VarLaster[NumVar];
                RadPos=StegLastAnt-AntAktuell;
                for (StegLastAnt2 = 0;StegLastAnt2<AntAktuell;StegLastAnt2++)
                {
                    VLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+0]=float(inLastP[1*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+1]);VLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+1]=float(inLastP[2*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+2]);VLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+2]=float(inLastP[3*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+3]);VLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+3]=float(inLastP[4*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+4]);VLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+4]=float(inLastP[5*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+5]);VLastP[StegLastAnt2*6+5]=float(inLastP[6*(sizeLastM-1)+RadPos+6]);
                    RadPos++;
                }
                NumVar++;
                AntAktuell=0;
                VLastP=nullptr;
        }
    AntAktuell++;
}
```

Its reading from input, and I have been debugging it, it works fine. I am deliberately avoiding an extra for-loop in there, to be sure of whats happening, and to make it easier to debug (though it looks less nice). It works fine, I have been looking at the values that are going in, and they are correct. No issues with corrupted adresses either.

Then after a lot of code its time to free it.

```
for (StegLastAnt= 0; StegLastAnt < AntPermLast;StegLastAnt++)
{
    free(PermLaster[StegLastAnt]);
}
```

Here it goes bananas and complains about heap corruption.

```
for (StegLastAnt= 0; StegLastAnt < AntVarLast-1;StegLastAnt++)
{
    free(VarLaster[StegLastAnt]);
}
free(PermLaster), free(VarLaster);
```

The functions through which the fields have gone through has all had the "PermLaster" as a const pointer const pointer to a const float. No addresses have beeen changed, no values in the inner field either. The memory seems fine, so why is this happening? Could it be that I have used different sizes for my subfields ( I have to for my application, no way around that)? Would it be better to use realloc instead? Switching to c++ with new and delete?

One more thing, the pointer to pointer PermLaster is declared as restrict through the function it is passed through. Is there an issue with that perhaps?

I am sure some of you will say use more structs or classes, but I am trying not to make the problem bigger than it is.

I would be very grateful for som good suggesttions here.

John

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger `gdb` and use a memory leak detector like `valgrind`. Also, give the operating system & compiler version in your question

Comment: Revision 3 of this question was a completely invalid edit, bordering vandalism - rolled back.

Comment: @icepack In what way? As far as I can see, the code display was corrected - which was reverted due to whatever reason...

Comment: Guys, what edit-war are you doing here?

Comment: @glglgl: See [Automatic code formatter (Ctrl+K) changes content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157910) I was going to add that indentation. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @John do you allocate `PermLaster` as `PermLaster= (float **) calloc(AntPermLast, sizeof(float*));` or as `PermLaster= (float *) calloc(AntPermLast, sizeof(float));`?

Comment: @icepack Good question and I think you're on the right track. Maybe replace free(PermLaster[StegLastAnt]) with free(*(PermLaster + StegLastAnt))?

Comment: with PermLaster= (float **) calloc(AntPermLast, sizeof(float*));
VarLaster= (float **) calloc(AntVarLast, sizeof(float*));, you only allocate space for one subfield in each array. You have to multiply the sizeof() by the number of subfields.

Comment: icepack: The first one is the one Im doing.

Comment: Marrow Gnower, Thanks for your comment, but I am allocating for a field with pointers to float not just floats. Maybe I should use realloc instead of calloc in the nested loop? BTW I am using Visual Studio 2010. Will the use of C99 make this whole problem go away, since you can do arbitrary fields on the stack? And thanks to all of you! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: `if (((int(inLastP[7*(sizeLastM-1)+StegLastAnt+7])== 0)|| ...` is a syntax error in C. Maybe this is this some other language? Also there are too many numeric literals (7 ...) in the program. And casting is unnecessary in C.

Comment: It's C with a touch of C++, compiled in Visual Studio 2010, so it goes through the compiler.

Comment: "Going through the compiler" does not make it C. Maybe VCC or VSC. Maybe SO needs a new tag for these polluted languages...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving us all the code. I suppose `NumPerm` and `NumVar` are reset to 0 between the loops.

By the way, there is another problem here:

```
        AntLastVekt[NumPerm]=AntAktuell;
```

Unless all "Perms" comes before all the "Vars", this should be AntLastVekt[NumPerm+NumVar].  Otherwise if you have a sequence Perm/Var/Perm, the second Perm will overwrite AntLastVekt[1].

However, this is not the cause of the problem because AntLastVekt is unused in the second loop.

The bug is in the second loop, even though the OS does not detect it until you free the arrays.  To prove this, comment out all the code in the middle.  You can use `valgrind` to debug it.

Comment: Thank you Paolo, all the perms do come before the vars, but Im changing that later to make it more general and user friendly. The AntLast is just a field in order to keep track of numbers and it's used later on. NumPerm and Var are reset to zero between the loops. Do you mean that there is a bug when I'm allocating for the inner fields in the first loop? I will look out for that. Thank you again!